# .htaccess; redirect do subdirectory without showing in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains like:

```
www.example.com
www.myexample.com
www.this-is-an-example.com
```

All domains point to the main path `/` on my server.

How can I point a single domain to a subdirectory on my server without showing un the URL?

I mean instead of `www.myexample.com` pointing to `/` on my server it should point to `/myexample/` on my server.

So calling `www.myexample.com` via browser should open `/myexample/index.php` on my server and NOT `/index.php`.

And `www.myexample.com/some_path/some_file.php` should look for `/myexample/some_path/some_file.php`non my server but the URL should remain `www.myexample.com/some_path/some_file.php` and get changed to `www.myexample.com/myexample/some_path/some_file.php`

Does anybody know how to do this? I already tried to  Google but without success maybe because I don't really know what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myexample\.com$
RewriteRule !folder /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will internally forward **www.myexample.com** or **myexample.com** (non-www) with requested uri to **/folder**

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule too,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myexample/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop, since domain/myexample also matches, it will try to redirect to domain/myexample/myexample, which also matches... etc...